# Overcome unnecessary characters in html string in Android?

Tags: android, html, html-encode

in RSS FEED. I am doing like this to supress html characters from string

```
public void setEncodedContent(String encodedContent) {
    //this.encodedContent = encodedContent;
    String noHTMLString = encodedContent.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
    this.encodedContent = noHTMLString;
}
```

But I am receiving characters like

&#8211
&#8217
&#8221

What is the way to overcome it ?

Regards

Comment: you can use xml pull parser to parse the tags required.

Comment: I have added solution in my own question. Thanks for all who helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Hope will be helpful to readers

```
public void setEncodedContent(String encodedContent) {
//this.encodedContent = encodedContent;
String noHTMLString = encodedContent.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
String yesHTMLString= Html.fromHtml(noHTMLString).toString();
this.encodedContent = yesHTMLString;

}
```